# Is it possible to use ?? operator in this case?

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

Suppose situation is the following:

```
dynamic? _rsomeFunc() {
    final smth = someGetFunction(); //may return null
    return smth != null ? someObject.fromJson(jsonDecode(smth)) : null;
}
```

is it possible to write it via `=>` in single line function? cause this approach is seems to be not perfect one. I tried it via `??` but it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: No, it is not possible.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1039 (or https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27716 or https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360).

Comment: @jamesdlin sad... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for references provided by @jamesdlin. For now (2022/02/10) in `Dart 2.16` there is no such opportunity;

Hope they will add it.